# Pair folder structures with github and web server for deployment setting

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I am working on a project now in a github environment.

On github it is like:

```
project-name-folder
-- application
-- htdocs
-- system
```

On web server side as we are running on a subdomain:

```
/
-- application
-- public_html
-- -- subdomain_name (counterpart of htdocs above)
-- system
```

How can I pair this two by configuring Deployment on PHP Storm? I need an answer or a light for an answer to digging up.

Comment: I'm not really sure on this one as I never used it myself, but "Mappings" tab of the Deployment entry has ability to provide multiple mappings. If you create 3 mappings it *may* work: application --> application; htdocs --> public_html; system --> system. Please try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mappping feature in PhpStorm and you can map folder by local, remote and relative path. You should set an deploy service first.

Answer (score 1):

Keep htdocs in your repository and create a symlink:

```
/
-- application
-- htdocs
-- public_html
-- -- subdomain_name -> ../htdocs
-- system
```

The symlink doesn't need to be under version control.